# Why is my 1993 Cadillac Deville acting like it's out of gas when the gauge says it still has fuel?

Tags: sensor, gasoline

I have a 1993 Deville. I put gas in it until it flows out. My fuel data system will say it's full, but then when it reads 15 gallons, the car acts likes it's out of gas. What's wrong?

Comment: How many miles between when you fill up and when you start seeing this behavior? It could be the main fuel sensor is going (gone) bad.

Comment: Also, is this a "Cadillac"? I've never heard of a "Carlos" ... very easily could have been autocorrect gone amuck!